# Not able to find the Xpath, really complicated for me. Need help

Tags: xpath

i am not able to find the xpath for a text box and get the value from it[image: enter [![enter image description here]

the code is here. please help me find the xpath to locate the box and get the value from it.

[image]

Comment: Why you insist on using Xpath, when your input has both name and ID? Also, we do not solve your homework. If you need to learn some basic skills, follow tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is so difficult here. Its pretty straight forward. The element has all possible attributes. You can write n number of correct xpath for this element.

```
//input[@name='sys_display.problem.assigned_to']
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way by inspecting the element and right clicking on the mouse will give you an option to copy the xpath